# Error C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'T'

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, compiler-errors, fstream

I try to compile the following code:

```
class CFileOperations
{
    ...
    template <typename T>
    inline void load_and_save_data(std::fstream* stream, T& value, const EOperation operation)
    {
        switch (operation) {
            case EOperation::OpSave:
                *stream << value;     <-- here
                break;
            case EOperation::OpLoad:
                *stream >> value;     <-- and here
                break;
        }
    }
    ...
};
```

I get the following errors:

```
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
Error   C2679   binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'T' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

For example, I use it this way, with number being an 'int':

```
this->load_and_save_data(stream, number, operation);
```

I'm using Visual C++ 2019.

What's the root cause, and how to solve it. Any idea ?

Comment: you have to define an `operator<<` function for ostream and any type you want to put in here

Comment: 1. It is not a ostream, but a fstream (but not sure it change anything to what's underlying my question).
2. fstream& operator << (stream& s, int i) doesn't exist yet?

Comment: In http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/
ostream& operator<< (int val);  for example.

Comment: fstream is derived from ostream, normal procedure is to write the function for ostream and then it is usable in other stream contexts

Comment: The int version already exists, your error is due to some other custom type. The error message should specify. Or possibly you haven't done `#include <fstream>`

Comment: If you are stil having trouble please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Be sure to check for informational messages the compiler prints before or after the actual errors, which could give more important details.

Comment: As an aside, I would definitely not make these the same function. Saving and loading should be different functions, if for no other reason than that you should be permitted to save a `const` value. The only way to do that using this API would be to make a mutable copy of the value first, which is wasteful and ugly.

Comment: @cdhowie. The scheme I'm putting in place (and that I already did about 30 years ago) is to get a methods save and load calling both load_and_save.  The advantage is that you maintain the code in one place, avoiding differences of order, types, or even avoiding missing data being loaded of saved.  Maintenance is much more easy.

Comment: My bad, one of the calls was with a 'class enum'. Of course, >> and << are not defined for it.

Comment: This site uses a Q/A format -- please put your solution in the Answer box and accept it, instead of editing it into the question

Comment: @Jacques The code isn't any more "in one place" than if you defined two functions one immediately below the other. This design is not const-correct. Beyond that, there is no separation of concerns -- one function should not be responsible for two things. (This is your code and you can do what you want, of course, but I'd strongly advise you to at least consider these issues.)

Comment: @cdhowie In everything one do, there are of course pros and cons. The "low level" function does indeed two things, and that's the purpose. But above that, this mechanism avoids this kind of "code duplication". For me, in some situations, the benefits are above the drawbacks. Of course, I wouldn't suggest mixing up functionalities everytime everywhere. IMHO, this is performed here in a limited and controlled way. Indeed the 'save' functionality is not const-correct.  I understand that this might be controversial but, for me, AFAIC the code above the "low level" is clean and easy to maintain.

Comment: @cdhowie "To accomplish the perfect perfection, a little imperfection helps." Dejan Stojanovic ;-)

Comment: @cdhowie, explaination in my second "answer" below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, one of the calls was with a 'class enum'. Of course, >> and << are not defined for it.

Answer (score 0):

For @cdhowie, here are two examples of the resulting simplicity (with the help of load_and_save_data template methods):

Here mMembers is a std::unorderedmap (cf. save_and_load_data in the question above, I have also one for the starndard containers):

```
void CHexArea::load_and_save()
{
    this->load_and_save_data((char&)mColor);
    this->load_and_save_data(mTouchLeft);
    this->load_and_save_data(mTouchRight);
    this->load_and_save_data(mTouchBottom);
    this->load_and_save_data(mTouchTop);

    this->load_and_save_data(mMembers);
}
```

Here, in preferences, there are two versions of files:

```
void CHexPreferences::load_and_save()
{
   if( this->is_loading() ) {
      this->reset(); // version's forward compatibility
   }

   int version = 2;
   this->load_and_save_data(version);
   this->load_and_save_data(mBoardOrientation);
   this->load_and_save_data(mBoardSize);
   this->load_and_save_data(mComputerStarts);
   this->load_and_save_data(mComputerInitialTurns);
   if( version >= 2) {
      this->load_and_save_data(mComputerTilesPerTurn);
   }
   this->load_and_save_data(mDebugFlags);
}
```

Simple and clear.

Of course, there are two methods (*load()* and *save()*) that are the outer interface and calls those here above, but: 1. They are part of a library (no need to rewrite them, OO as usual) and 2. The core of the load/save is written only once in load_save_data, with the advantage of simplicity, and having corresponding load and save code (types, order...).

Of course, there are cons, but I hope you'll see that it may make sense for some people to think that there are (IMHO very strong) pros as well.

The rest is a matter of taste.